# build month Start and End dates intervals SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have my getdate() = '2022-03-21 09:24:34.313'

I'd like to build Start Month and End Month dates intervals with SQL language (SQL server) , with the following screen :

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15   What DB are you using?????

Comment: It's unclear what you want or what this image is supposed to show. The solution will almost certainly involve creating a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with prepopulated Start and End Of Month columns. You only need to create such a table once for eg 20 years and use it to simplify almost every date-related query or report

Comment: Note that `2022-03-31 00:00:00` is *not* the end of the month. You should use an exclusive end time of `2022-04-01 00:00:00`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EOMONTH` function and `DATEADD` function to get the data you want.

But, the best approach would be to use a calendar table and map it against the current date and get the data you want.

```sql
DECLARE @DATE DATE = getdate()

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@DATE,-1)) AS MonthM_Start, EOMONTH(@DATE) AS MonthM_End,
       DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@DATE,-2)) AS MonthOneBack_Start, EOMONTH(@DATE,-1) AS MonthOneBack_End,
       DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@DATE,-3)) AS MonthTwoBack_Start, EOMONTH(@DATE,-2) AS MonthTwoBack_End,
       DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@DATE,-4)) AS MonthThreeBack_Start, EOMONTH(@DATE,-3) AS MonthThreeBack_End
```

| MonthM_Start | MonthM_End | MonthOneBack_Start | MonthOneBack_End | MonthTwoBack_Start | MonthTwoBack_End | MonthThreeBack_Start | MonthThreeBack_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-31 |

Comment: Hello friend, it's very useful thanks ! just i want to use it in stored procedure for other processing .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to avoid having to hard-code an expression for each month boundary you need, making it very easy to handle fewer or more months by just changing a parameter.

Do you really need the end date for processing? Seems more appropriate for a label, since date/time types can vary - meaning the last day of the month *at midnight* isn't very useful if you're trying to pull any data from *after* midnight on the last day of the month.

This also shows how to display the data for each month even if there isn't any data in the table for that month.

```
DECLARE @number_of_months int = 4,
  @today date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1);

;WITH m(s) AS
(
  SELECT @today UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, s) FROM m
  WHERE s > DATEADD(MONTH, 1-@number_of_months, @today)
)
SELECT MonthStart = m.s, MonthEnd = EOMONTH(m.s)--, other cols/aggs
FROM m
--LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SourceTable AS t
--ON t.datetime_column >= m
--AND t.datetime_column < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m);
```

Output (without the join):

> | MonthStart | MonthEnd |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-31 |
> | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-28 |
> | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
> | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-31 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fef5c40fc1342329854c945fc0a0df11)

But, as mentioned in a comment, you could easily store this information in [a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), too, and just outer join to that:

```
SELECT c.TheFirstOfMonth, c.TheLastOfMonth --, other cols/aggs
  FROM dbo.CalendarTable AS c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SourceTable AS t
  ON t.datetime_column >= c.TheFirstOfMonth
    AND t.datetime_column < c.TheFirstOfNextMonth
  WHERE c.FirstOfMonth >= DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())
    AND c.FirstOfMonth < GETDATE();
```